# Getting ClasscastException for Suggester code written in SolrJ

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, autosuggest

I have configured Suggester in Solr and by using the below URL i am able to get the results.

http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q=Mo

But to achieve the same with SolrJ code I am getting the below exception at line 7 of further below snippet.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse.setResponse(QueryResponse.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:957)
    at com.finder.testsearch.SolrJBeanSearcher.main(SolrJBeanSearcher.java:71)

Code:

```
SolrQuery suggestionQuery = new SolrQuery();
suggestionQuery.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
suggestionQuery.set("suggest", "true");
suggestionQuery.set("suggest.build", "true");
suggestionQuery.set("suggest.dictionary", "mySuggester");
suggestionQuery.set("suggest.q", "Hom");
QueryResponse suggestionResponse = solr.query(suggestionQuery);

SuggesterResponse suggesterResponse = 
suggestionResponse.getSuggesterResponse();
Map<String,List<String>> suggestedTerms = 
suggesterResponse.getSuggestedTerms();
List<String> suggestions = suggestedTerms.get("mySuggester");
```

Below are solrconfig.xml entries.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
  <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
  <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
  <str name="field">tagsList</str>
  <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
  <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler"
                  startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="suggest">true</str>
  <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleOrderedMap does not relate to  java.util.Map so that is why you get this error.

See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_0_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/util/SimpleOrderedMap.html

Comment: The SolJ code is throwing exception so I am looking for some answer around that. I know why ClassCastException occurs.

Comment: I see. Do you have the proper version of SolrJ for the Solr you have? What versions are you using?

Comment: This is not your code then? Map<String,List<String>> suggestedTerms = 
suggesterResponse.getSuggestedTerms();

Comment: I am getting exception at the bottom line.    QueryResponse suggestionResponse = solr.query(suggestionQuery);  I am using Solr 7

Comment: What version of SolrJ are you using?